# r.watershed analysis error from raster map being in different zone and unable to be opened

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins

I tried running my DEM (geotiff) file through the `r.watershed` program by the GRASS GIS plugin of QGIS.  I believe the error message results from a raster map in the different zone than the current region but I set my GRASS GIS mapset in WGS84-Zone 16N coordinate system where it ought to be.

Here is the error message I get:

```
r.watershed elevation=dem2@Tejeras threshold=30 accumulation=dem2_accum drainage=dem2_drain stream=dem2_stream basin=dem2_basin

SECTION 1a (of 5): Initiating Memory.

￼Raster map is in different zone (16) than current region (0)

￼Unable to open raster map 

￼unable to open elevation map layer

￼Subprocess failed with exit code 1

￼category information for [dem2_accum] in [Tejeras] missing or invalid

￼category information for [dem2_drain] in [Tejeras] missing or invalid

￼category information for [dem2_basin] in [Tejeras] missing or invalid

￼category information for [dem2_stream] in [Tejeras] missing or invalid
Finished with error
```

Answer (score 2):

Go into Grass GIS interface and look for g.region (should be under Settings->Region->Set Region. Since my raster file (geotiff) was already set in WGS84-UTM 16N Zone I just needed to use the second option (labled as '[multiple] Set Region to match this Raster Map') and select my raster file (which happens to be a DEM). Then click Run and your done.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 2.8, open the GRASS tool g.region.multiple.raster. Even if you only want to set the region to one raster, you can use this tool to solve the "Raster map is in different zone" problem. Just type the name of your raster(s).